# Gradle | Configuration with name 'complileClasspath' not found. for multi-level project build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to build a multi-project build in Gradle using Kotlin DSL.

Root `build.gradle.kts`:

```
allprojects { 
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    }
}
subprojects{
    version = "1.0"
}

plugins {
    java
    application
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "gradle.youtube.series.App"
}
```

gitutils subproject's `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {


    implementation("org.sl4j:sl4j-api:1.7.2")
    implementation("org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.3.0.201903130848-r")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.sl4j:sl4j-simple:1.7.2")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am trying to download gradeutil's dependencies using the following command:

```
 ./gradlew gitutils:dependencies --configuration complileClasspath
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Configuration with name 'complileClasspath' not found.
```

Is compileClassPath required for multi-level gradle project? What is its use?

Comment: There is an spelling error in `--configuration complileClasspath` .  compileClasspath — FileCollection
Default value: ${name}CompileClasspath configuration

The classpath to use when compiling the source files of this source set